# Component for inputting email addesses

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I want to design a component for inputting and handling mail addresses, the EXACTLY SAME way that hotmail does it. Can you tell me which Flex components are most suitable to do this as I am totally lost with this.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are not any that do this straight out of the box but a [TextInput](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/spark/components/TextInput.html#propertySummary) plus some [validation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ff0.html) and maybe some event handlers will do the trick.

Comment: DO I need to use ItemRenderer to handle each email address individually, since I will need to delete or edit each address upon clicking on icons on each address as hotmail does it.